# How to create an aggregated table in python panda?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, date, datetime

In python notebook, I have extracted a detail table in time series from database.

df = data.select("*").toPandas()

Which the indicator is deduced by the value is larger than 2 or smaller than -2 (null value will consider as Y):

df =

| Key | Time | Indicator | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2021-01-01 00:00 | Y | 2.00 |
| A | 2021-01-01 00:15 | Y | 3.00 |
| A | 2021-01-01 00:30 | N | 1.00 |
| A | 2021-01-01 00:45 | Y | 10.00 |
| A | 2021-01-01 01:10 | Y | 8.00 |
| A | 2021-01-01 01:20 | Y | 6.00 |
| A | 2021-01-01 01:40 | Y | 4.00 |
| A | 2021-01-01 02:05 | Y | -- |
| A | 2021-01-01 02:20 | N | -1.50 |
| B | 2021-01-01 02:55 | Y | -3.00 |
| B | 2021-01-01 03:00 | N | -0.50 |
| B | 2021-01-01 03:05 | Y | -4.00 |
| C | 2021-01-01 03:25 | Y | 3.00 |
| C | 2021-01-01 03:35 | Y | 3.00 |
| C | 2021-01-01 03:50 | Y | -- |

I would like to calculate a new table with below criteria:

1. within the same key
2. consecutive indicator = Y

then create a row with start time, end time, duration, max. value and min. value

which:

start_time = first row of the indicator = Y of the same key **AND**

(end_time = next row of the last record of indicator = Y of the same key **OR**

end_time = last row of the last record of indicator = Y if the next record is different key)

Then calculate the duration, max. value and min value of each subset.

While the max. and min. values will not consider null values.

Resulting:

df_s =

| Key | start_time | end_time | duration(min) | max_value | min_value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2021-01-01 00:00 | 2021-01-01 00:30 | 30.00 | 3.00 | 2.00 |
| A | 2021-01-01 00:45 | 2021-01-01 02:20 | 95.00 | 10.00 | 4.00 |
| B | 2021-01-01 02:55 | 2021-01-01 03:00 | 5.00 | -3.00 | -3.00 |
| C | 2021-01-01 03:05 | 2021-01-01 03:25 | 20.00 | -4.00 | -4.00 |
| C | 2021-01-01 03:25 | 2021-01-01 03:50 | 25.00 | 3.00 | 5.00 |

How should I calculate **df** to create the new table **df_s** ?

Thank you!

Comment: Is it really necessary to have different criteria of `end_time` for same key and different key ?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
# Read in dataframe from clipboard
df = pd.read_clipboard()

# Do some datatyping and replace '--' with np.nan
df['Value'] = df['Value'].replace('--', np.nan)
df['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time'])
df['Value'] = pd.to_numeric(df['Value'])

# Create logic from grouping and exclude 'N' records values
cond = df['Indicator'] == 'N'
dft = df.assign(Value=df['Value'].mask(cond))

# Create groups
g = (cond).cumsum()

# Groupby and create aggregations
df_out = dft.groupby(['Key', g.shift().bfill()])\
            .agg(start_time=('Time', 'min'),
                 end_time=('Time', 'max'),
                 duration=('Time',lambda x: (x.iloc[-1] - x.iloc[0]).total_seconds() / 60),
                 max_value=('Value','max'),
                 min_value=('Value','min'))

df_out
```

Output:

```
                       start_time            end_time  duration  max_value  min_value
Key Indicator                                                                        
A   0.0       2021-01-01 00:00:00 2021-01-01 00:30:00      30.0        3.0        2.0
    1.0       2021-01-01 00:45:00 2021-01-01 02:20:00      95.0       10.0        4.0
B   2.0       2021-01-01 02:55:00 2021-01-01 03:00:00       5.0       -3.0       -3.0
    3.0       2021-01-01 03:05:00 2021-01-01 03:05:00       0.0       -4.0       -4.0
C   3.0       2021-01-01 03:25:00 2021-01-01 03:50:00      25.0        3.0        3.0
```